# Can't save text to a file

Tags: php, file, save, fwrite

I have the following sequence of code:

```
$fp = fopen('script.sh', 'wt');
fwrite($fp, 'some text');
fclose($fp);
```

Now this should write `some text` to script.sh, simple and clear and worked for a while. But since yesterday script.sh is always empty, even though `some text` is not empty at all. The funny part is that no errors are returned. Also if I type manually something inside script.sh and then run the code script.sh is empty again.

Permissions are `777`. The file is correct (if I delete it it says that the file does not exist).

Comment: Is this the only place you write to the file? It sounds like something else might be writing to that file and removing the contents

Comment: What `fwrite($fp, 'some text');` returns?

Comment: No... I found the answer and is kind of stupid :)). I've run out of space and could not save the file. So... sorry for a lame post. Forgot to check the most basing thing.

Comment: Then please either delete this question or write an answer yourself and accept it, so we can see that this doesn't need our attention anymore.

Comment: Can't delete questions with answers and can't accept my own answer before 2 days. So I'll just accept a random answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no FOPEN mode 'wt' so it will default to WRITE as defined in the PHP doc:

> Open for writing only; place the file
>   pointer at the beginning of the file
>   and truncate the file to zero length.
>   If the file does not exist, attempt to
>   create it.

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Open the file with either APPEND (a) or WRITE (w) mode in order to write data to the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

is it `'w+'` instead of `'wt'`?

Answer (score 0):

Run out of space and the file could not be saved any more. Works ok now.